# highcharts - Remove only legend for colorAxis (keep legend for series)

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, heatmap

I have heatmap and scatter in one plot. I tried to remove the legend of colorAxis (for heatmap). The only solution I found on web is to remove the whole legend what I do not want since I want to keep the legend for scatter.

So the flowing example does not solve the problem. I still want to have a legend. I want to remove just part for colorAxis.

```
legend: {
  enabled: false
}
```

I want to have something like this with only Seriest 2 in legend. 
http://jsfiddle.net/9mL8x9bc/4/

Comment: You may hide this colorAxis in your load event callback function using Element.hide() method: http://jsfiddle.net/9mL8x9bc/6/

Comment: Thanks @GrzegorzBlachliński. But there is one more problem. When I remove it the legend have still same height. You can see that if you set the background color. Since I want to use legend with white background I want also that is smaller. http://jsfiddle.net/9mL8x9bc/8/
Is there any way how to change that?

Comment: You can add symbolWidth and symbolHeight to your legend and set it to 0, it should help:http://jsfiddle.net/9mL8x9bc/9/

Answer (score 0):

Try ...

```
legend: false
```

This works for me